# Access to Gmail from Unknown User

Tags: gmail, security

At the bottom of my Gmail, there is a link to show the history. I realized there was someone from the US going on my account, but when o changed my password they still had access. Is this just part of the system? The User changes IP addresses every time they use my account. I haven't noticed them doing anything, so should I be concerned? It usually looks like this: Authorized Application (-numbers here-.apps.googleusercontent.com) with numbers before the .apps.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Google account, and check the security section to see if there are any applications that you have granted access to.

It is a good thing to check this every so often to make sure you haven't accidentally granted access to something you didn't intend to.

Comment: I have done so now. I checked but the only two devices there are my phone and my computer.

Comment: You aren't checking for a device. You are checking for an application you granted access. The clue is "Authorised Application (-numbers here-.apps.googleusercontent.com) with numbers before the .apps."